# How to retrieve jsonObjects from a arraylist api response in Java

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How to get `jsonObjects` from this below rest `api` response, using `restAassured` and `java`.

My rest `api` is returning response as below.

```
[
    {
        "id": {
            "value": "1"
        },
        "fieldName": "input",
        "jobId": "234"
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "value": "2"
        },
        "fieldName": "output",
        "jobId": "223"
    }
]
```

I have tried using `rest assured` response parsing methods like `jsonPath()`, `getJsonObject()` etc., nothing works. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.readValue(<OUTPUT_STRING>,ArrayNode.class)
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh, I am not clear on how to use your solution on restassured API response. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Santosh, it worked for me. I was using restassured objectmapper initially later tried jackson core one, it worked.